# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to add orwhere using the below syntax for searching :

```
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where(DB::raw("g.title"), 'LIKE', "%{$query}%");
    $query->orWhere(DB::raw("s.step"), 'LIKE', "%{$query}%");
})
```

but I'm receiving the below error

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string
```

It is working fine if I used the normal syntax as below :

```
->where(DB::raw("g.title"), 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
->orwhere(DB::raw("s.step"), 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
```

But I will add another where condition, so I have to use the first syntax.

Comment: `$query` is used both as parameter than in `%$query%` . You need to use a different var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `$query` twice. Both in your `where()` `Closure` and as a value. Also when you use closures and what to access values from outside the scope you have to use the `use()` statement. This code is not included but i assume it looks something similar to this and will work like that.

```
// replace this with whatever $query is in your code, from outside the closure scope
$search = $request->get('query');

Model::query()
    ->where(function($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where(DB::raw("g.title"), 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
        $query->orWhere(DB::raw("s.step"), 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
    })
    ->get();
```